# Parsing Json date in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been making an app for my student association and got it linked with a calendar api. 
My problem is that the starttime is in Json format.

At the moment I've imported it like this

```
title: Text("${userData[index]["start"]}",
```

I know there is an easy way to parse html to normal, but is this also possible with json? 
My datetime looks like this at the moment : {datetime:2020-05-13T19:00:00+02:00} at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

This may work

```
title: Text('${userData[index]["start"]["datetime"]}'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also escape the double quotation with a backslash before that, like this :

```
title: Text("${userData[index][\"start\"]}",
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! At least i lost the "datetime", now I have to figure out how to parse this: 020-05-13T19:00:00+02:00.